# Append rows to datatable in foreach c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datarow

I need to append rows one by one. The below code only adds the current rows and how can I add rows on top of the existing ones?

```
DataTable dt = new .DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Property", typeof(string));
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

foreach (Object form in Obj)
{
    string str1 = "hi";
    string str2 = "hey";
    row["Name"] = str1;
    row["Property"] = str2;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Really appreciate any suggestions?

**Update 1:**

My actual code

```
 System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("Property", typeof(string));

 if (crobj.SourceName.StartsWith("{@"))
   {
     foreach (CRObject crform in lstObj)
       {
         if (crform.FormulaForm == crobj.SourceName)
           {                                                            
             System.Data.DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
             newRow["Name"] = "hi";
             newRow["Property"] = "hey";                                                            
             dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
           }                                                        
       }
   }
```

Comment: `DataRow row = dt.NewRow();` should be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Small change:

```
DataTable dt = new .DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Property", typeof(string));

foreach (Object form in Obj)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();   <<<------------
    string str1 = "hi";
    string str2 = "hey";
    row["Name"] = str1;
    row["Property"] = str2;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

By generating a new row inside the loop, it is treated as a new row instead of the same one.

EDIT: if this doesn't work, then the Obj collection is probably not containing values. Try this to test:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Property", typeof(string));

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();   
    string str1 = "hi";
    string str2 = "hey";
    row["Name"] = str1;
    row["Property"] = str2;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

With this, the resulting data table contains 5 rows.

Comment: Still my datatable doesn't append rows.

Comment: What is Obj? How many items are in there? If you debug, do you see the foreach loop is executed multiple times? Just tested this and it works, so I'm guessing you don't have items in the Obj collection.

Comment: Obj is a generics list and it has items. Also foreach loops is executing multiple times. FYI, foreach has an if condition and does that make any difference?

Comment: @Vicky how do you check whether `dt` has more rows after the loop?

Comment: @MongZhu - I check in the `dt` where the object is created using the magnifier and I dont' see rows getting appended.

Comment: @vicky: I added an example with a 'for' loop, to prove that it should work. If it doesn't, and your loop is actually executed a number of times, then something in your loop is not correct. Debug your code to see what happens. The 'if' condition may cause issues, of course, but without seeing it, it's only guessing :)

Comment: @L-Four - When I debug it enter the loop and there is no problem with that. If condition is a boolean check and it shouldn't cause any problems with this.

Comment: Just check if the statement 'dt.Rows.Add(row);' is hit multiple times or not.

Comment: @L-Four - Yes, it does.

Comment: So then the resulting data table should contain multiple entries in its Rows property.

Comment: @L-Four - Can you pls move this to chat?

Comment: (no, have to get my train in a minute, sorry)

Comment: Update your post with a reproducable example, it's easier to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: In the meanwhile, did you find the problem?

Comment: @L-Four - Yes. When I debugged I found the datatable values get reset whenever it enters the below if condition.` Is there any way I can add those rows to datatable somewhere apart from this place. It's actually a big event where it completely comes out of the if condition and it enter when the conditions matches and so the datatable gets reset. 

`if (crform.FormulaForm == crobj.SourceName)` is it possible for a chat with you? It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one `row` (`DataRow`) object which you keep re-editing.  Declare a new one within the scope of the loop:

```
foreach (Object form in Obj)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    //...
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```